# Emacs Ruby Electric Does Not Insert End

Tags: ruby, emacs

I have Ruby Electric mode installed via ELPA.

I have visited a ruby file `~/test.rb`

`C-h m` reveals that ruby electric mode is enabled as is font lock, see output below

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor Column-Number 
Delete-Selection File-Name-Shadow Global-Font-Lock Global-Linum Iswitchb Line-Number 
Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Shell-Dirtrack Tooltip Transient-Mark
```

However when I enter code like;

```
class Test
  def foo()
```

I don't get any `end` auto inserted on hitting `RET`

**UPDATE**

I installed via `package-list` as that was recommended on the page I found, which I thought belonged to the author.  Looking at the source of `~/emacs.d/elpa/ruby-electric-1.1/ruby-electric.el` I see the following;

```
;; FIXME: it should be available in next versions of ruby-mode.el
(defun ruby-insert-end ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "end")
  (ruby-indent-line t)
  (end-of-line))
```

So it looks like I might have a bad file, will try another.

**UPDATE**

I used `ruby-electric.el` downloaded from http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_2_0/misc/ruby-electric.el

Linked to from this article http://appsintheopen.com/articles/1-setting-up-emacs-for-rails-development/part/7-emacs-ruby-foo

Then took this gist https://gist.github.com/1213051 adding this to `ruby-electric.el`

```
(defun ruby-insert-end () 
  "Insert \"end\" at point and reindent current line." 
  (interactive) 
  (insert "end") 
  (ruby-indent-line t) 
  (end-of-line))
```

And this hook into my `.emacs`, it also appears to work without the hook

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (require 'ruby-electric)
        (ruby-electric-mode t)))
```

As discussed in this google groups thread; https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/emacs-on-rails/Cuh_x5eCK_M/KDwjY4K6X1YJ

Comment: Note that electric modes usually work directly on space or special characters like ({" etc..not on `RET`. So `class` + space is electric.

Comment: Interesting, I'm getting a `Symbol's function definition is void: ruby-insert-end` when I hit space after def or class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure it says `REl` in your Emacs status bar.

I downloaded ruby-electric from here:
http://shylock.uw.hu/Emacs/ruby-electric.el

I then loaded the library into Emacs, and went into a ruby file and activated
ruby electric with:

```
M-x ruby-electric-mode
```

When I type `class` and hit space it fills in the `end` automatically (running Emacs 23). Maybe you want to give that version of `ruby-electric.el` a try, if you can't get the one from ELPA to work.

Comment: I ended up using `ruby-electric.el` linked to from here; http://appsintheopen.com/articles/1-setting-up-emacs-for-rails-development/part/7-emacs-ruby-foo

Comment: Am accepting this answer as using something other than the ELPA versions has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to include 'ruby-additional' to use 'ruby-electric':

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/misc/ruby-additional.el

Should be merged in emacs some day.

Comment: I've switched to using Prelude and ruby electric in there has worked fine for me since day one.

Comment: Cool. Also check out https://github.com/rejeep/ruby-tools.el for more ruby-mode sugarcoat =D